# Как запустить все Python юнит-тесты в директории?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, python-unittest

Можно ли запустить все юнит-тесты в директории одной командой (стандартный модуль `unittest`)?

```
test/
    test_mytest1.py
    test_mytest2.py
```

Comment: Что не так с моим само-ответом? Полностью аналогичный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732438/20137863 (правда более длинный) не вызвал негативной реакции.

Comment: заведи себе бригаду из 20 челов и наматывай счётчик. у тебя нет проблемы, нет ошибки, самому тут не принято отвечать на вопросы. это вопрос этики. даже не деловой этики.

Comment: Только что читал на мете залайканные посты про полезные само-ответы и полезность "заметочнечества" для комьюнити. Видимо это ещё более субъективная штука.

Comment: кажный кулик свое болото хвалит, вы обращаетесь за помощью. как правило. но всегда находятся люди серии "здесь был вася". бестолковый вопрос со своим же бестолковым ответом. ради чего? вот напиши мне, ради чего?

Comment: далее. unittests нафиг никому не нужны, прошлый век, pytest это делает автоматом, проблем с чтением документации по указанному фреймворку никаких вопросов нет и вопросы. соотвественно, никогда не возникает. просто прочёл и запустил. соотвественно, ваш вопрос вообще без аудитории и ценности не представляет. ни-ка-кой.

Comment: @nexoma Ради чего? За само-ответ даже знак дают.

Comment: лады, отдано на рассмотрение модераторов.

Comment: @nexoma https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: друзья, это замусоривание. подумайте сами. я допускаю самоответ в куче других, в споре, диалоге, обсуждении. но тут? один вопрос - один самоответ. это точно stackoverflow?

Comment: @nexoma не засоряйте комментарии. Давайте остановим беседу для чистоты, вам всё сказали.

Comment: ну aepot выбран модератором. ок.

Comment: @nexoma ознакомьтесь со статьёй в справке. Если после этого остались вопросы, предлагаю задать вопрос на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) или обсудить в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/?tab=site&sort=active).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого применяется сабкоманда [discover](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery):

```
python -m unittest discover <directory>
```

Также есть флаг `-p, --pattern` - "Pattern to match test files", по умолчанию `test*.py`:

```
python -m unittest discover -s <directory> -p "test*.py"
```

Запуск необязательно производить в самой директории с тестами (`.py` файлами) - каталоги и подкаталоги, содержащие тесты, могут быть пакетами, имеющими `__init__.py` файл, поиск будет совершён рекурсивно.